Mass Insertion Feynman Diagram Amplitude
I want to evaluate the diagram displayed below. It is a specific Higgs transition to a photon via a loop interaction with quarks. The diagram is the following.

Of course, the pertinent interaction lagrangian from the Standard Model is the Yukawa Coupling of the mass of the looping quark and the electromagnetic vertex. The expressions are the following:
\begin{equation}
L_{QED} = -eQA_{\mu}\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\psi = -eQA_{\mu}\bar{\psi}_L\gamma^{\mu}\psi_L+-eQA_{\mu}\bar{\psi}_R\gamma^{\mu}\psi_R
\end{equation}
Restricting ourselves to the top quark and omitting the flavour structure after SSB
\begin{equation}
L_{mass} = -y_th\bar{t}_Rt_L +h.c= - y_th\bar{t}P_Lt+h.c
\end{equation}
It becomes apparent that this diagram can not exist unless we consider a mass insertion which flips the chirality of one of the propagating legs. The diagram would have the following form.

To evaluate this diagram now, I pass to two-component spinor formalism (It is the only formalism I know to consistently treat mass insertions). The corresponding Lagrangian terms in two-component formalism would be given by:
\begin{equation}
L^{L}_{int} = -eQA_{\mu}\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}P_L\psi - y_th\bar{t}P_Lt = -eQA_{\mu}\chi^{\dagger}\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}\chi - y_th\eta\chi
\end{equation}
I use the 4-component Dirac spinor convention $\Psi= (\chi_a,\eta^{\dagger \dot{a}})^{T}$. From the above the Feynman Rules can be derived but most importantly, the mass insertion mechanism becomes apparent, using the chiral field propagators as presented in the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.1594. Nonetheless, I can not make the connection to 4-component spinor. How can we treat consistently in 4-component spinor the chirality flip trick?
